# Why can't I used the disambiguate operator correctly in Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

```
grunt> describe aa
aa: {header: int}
grunt> aa = FOREACH aa GENERATE aa::header as h2; 
2015-08-18 00:09:56,405 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1025: 
<line 7, column 25> Invalid field projection. Projected field [aa::header] does not exist in schema: header:int.
Details at logfile: /export/home/capsrch/pig_1439855906404.log
grunt> aa = FOREACH aa GENERATE header as h2;    
grunt> describe aa;
aa: {h2: int}
```

My question is why did `FOREACH aa GENERATE aa::header as h2;` on line 3 fail. Am I not using the `::` operator right there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#disambiguate

**Extract from above link :**

```
Use the disambiguate operator ( :: ) to identify field names after JOIN, COGROUP, CROSS, or FLATTEN operators.
```

Was 'aa' alias derived after any of this operator : JOIN, COGROUP, CROSS, or FLATTEN ? If not then there is no ambiguity to resolve using the Disambiguate Operator.